# MySQL How Can I Group By With A Wildcard

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to group rows together with a wildcard. Is this possible?

My table has the following rows:

```
   Region
```

1. South
2. South: Miami
3. South: Miami: Miami Beach
4. South: Miami
5. South
6. South: Miami: Miami Beach
7. South
8. South: Miami

Currently using the following query:

```
SELECT `region`, count(*) as `TOTAL` FROM `table` WHERE 1=1  group by `region`
```

Which gives the following output:
      Region                       Total

```
 1. South                            3
 2. South: Miami                     3
 3. South: Miami: Miami Beach        2
```

How can I adjust the query to give the followinng output?

```
 Region                       Total

 1. South                            8
 2. South: Miami                     5
 3. South: Miami: Miami Beach        2
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That query already gives the desired output, not the output you say it gives.

Comment: Yeah, it already should give the second output.

Comment: If you want however the first output, you can't do that in a single query afaik. Because each row is returned at most once, so the total of the group-by count() should never exceed the database size.

Comment: Sorry, i had edited the question and forgot to rotate the sample output.

Comment: The answer to your revised question is to normalize the database. Don't store 3 pieces of data in one column then the query would be trivial (`group by region, city, zone` or whatever).

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the fact that this doesn't follow the basic principles of normalization (I've had times myself when I didn't need to go that far), this HACKERY should work:

```
SELECT a.region, (a.total + COUNT(b.region)) AS total 
FROM 
    ( SELECT region, COUNT(*) AS total 
      FROM table 
      GROUP BY region
    ) AS a
  LEFT JOIN table b 
    ON b.region LIKE CONCAT(a.region, ":%")
GROUP BY a.region
```

Keep in mind you MUST have an index on region, and you'd be MUCH better off with a normalized table (i.e. Region, ParentRegion).  Cheers!